# PPO: NaN Policy return in Tensorflow Keras

Tags: tensorflow, keras, reinforcement-learning, gradient-descent

I am trying to implement the PPO algorithm with clipped loss in addition to KL penalties and run training on Mujuco Gym environments. After ~ 15000 gradient steps, policy collapses into returning NaN.

These are the policy training info before the policy collapses:

```
A:  tf.Tensor(-0.10426917, shape=(), dtype=float32)
LOG_A:  tf.Tensor(37.021107, shape=(), dtype=float32)
LOSS:  tf.Tensor(0.16812761, shape=(), dtype=float32)
GRAD:  tf.Tensor(
[[-3.4624012e-04 -1.2807851e-04 -1.9778654e-01 ... -2.7586846e+00
  -1.2552655e-01 -1.7212760e-03]
 [ 4.6312678e-05 -2.2251482e-04  5.5088173e-03 ...  9.5249921e-02
   2.2186586e-03  2.0080474e-04]
 [ 2.0314787e-05 -1.6381161e-04  7.1509695e-03 ...  1.1740552e-01
   3.4010289e-03  1.2105847e-04]
 ...
 [ 1.7827883e-04 -1.1712313e-05  5.8873045e-01 ...  9.2354174e+00
   2.9186043e-01 -2.2818900e-03]
 [-9.0385452e-05  3.0951984e-03 -3.6487404e-02 ... -2.6829168e-01
  -3.9602429e-02  2.0654879e-03]
 [ 2.2925157e-04  4.6892464e-03  5.9946489e-01 ...  9.3497839e+00
   3.0514282e-01 -1.3834883e-03]], shape=(11, 256), dtype=float32)
A:  tf.Tensor(nan, shape=(), dtype=float32)
LOG_A:  tf.Tensor(nan, shape=(), dtype=float32)
```

**Note:** The gradient info captures only the gradients of the first layer, as I have found capturing all gradient info to be messy and seemingly redundant.

**What I have tried:**

1. Tuning hyperparameters: I have tried multiple sets of hyperparameters including the one documented in the original paper. The same error occurs(the hyperparams setup provided in the example below are chosen for higher sampling efficiency for faster debugging).
2. Gradient clipping: Gradient norm has been clipped to be unitary, and as shown above, it does not appear to have the exploding gradient issue.
3. Guaranteed numerical stability of tanh squashing of policy log probability: A small epsilon was used to clip the sum of squares so that action log probability does not return inf after tanh squashing.

**Unitized code example:**

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras import layers
import gym
import scipy.signal
import time
from tensorflow.keras import Model
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import random
import tensorflow_probability as tfp

tf.keras.backend.set_floatx('float32')

EPSILON = 1e-10

################## GLOBAL SETUP P1 ##################

problem = "Hopper-v2"
env = gym.make(problem)
eval_env = gym.make(problem)

num_states = env.observation_space.shape[0]
print("Size of State Space ->  {}".format(num_states), flush=True)
num_actions = env.action_space.shape[0]
print("Size of Action Space ->  {}".format(num_actions), flush=True)

upper_bound = env.action_space.high[0]
lower_bound = env.action_space.low[0]

print("Max Value of Action ->  {}".format(upper_bound), flush=True)
print("Min Value of Action ->  {}".format(lower_bound), flush=True)

minibatch_size = 256

##########*****####################*****##########

#################### Auxiliaries ####################

def discounted_cumulative_sums(x, discount):
    # Discounted cumulative sums of vectors for computing rewards-to-go and advantage estimates
    return scipy.signal.lfilter([1], [1, float(-discount)], x[::-1], axis=0)[::-1]


##########*****####################*****##########


#################### Replay Buffer ####################

class Buffer:

    def __init__(self, observation_dimensions, action_dimensions, size, gamma=0.99, lam=0.95):

        self.observation_buffer = np.zeros(
            (size, observation_dimensions), dtype=np.float32
        )
        self.action_buffer = np.zeros((size, action_dimensions), dtype=np.int32)
        self.advantage_buffer = np.zeros(size, dtype=np.float32)
        self.reward_buffer = np.zeros(size, dtype=np.float32)
        self.return_buffer = np.zeros(size, dtype=np.float32)
        self.value_buffer = np.zeros(size, dtype=np.float32)
        self.logprobability_buffer = np.zeros(size, dtype=np.float32)
        self.gamma, self.lam = gamma, lam
        self.pointer, self.trajectory_start_index = 0, 0

    def store(self, observation, action, reward, value, logprobability):

        self.observation_buffer[self.pointer] = observation
        self.action_buffer[self.pointer] = action
        self.reward_buffer[self.pointer] = reward
        self.value_buffer[self.pointer] = value
        self.logprobability_buffer[self.pointer] = logprobability
        self.pointer += 1

    def finish_trajectory(self, last_value=0):

        path_slice = slice(self.trajectory_start_index, self.pointer)
        rewards = np.append(self.reward_buffer[path_slice], last_value)
        values = np.append(self.value_buffer[path_slice], last_value)

        deltas = rewards[:-1] + self.gamma * values[1:] - values[:-1]

        self.advantage_buffer[path_slice] = discounted_cumulative_sums(
            deltas, self.gamma * self.lam
        )
        self.return_buffer[path_slice] = discounted_cumulative_sums(
            rewards, self.gamma
        )[:-1]

        self.trajectory_start_index = self.pointer

    def get(self):
        # Get all data of the buffer and normalize the advantages
        rindex = np.random.choice(self.pointer, minibatch_size)
        advantage_mean, advantage_std = (
            np.mean(self.advantage_buffer[rindex]),
            np.std(self.advantage_buffer[rindex]),
        )
        return (
            self.observation_buffer[rindex],
            self.action_buffer[rindex],
            (self.advantage_buffer[rindex] - advantage_mean) / advantage_std,
            self.return_buffer[rindex],
            self.logprobability_buffer[rindex],
        )
    def clear(self):
        self.pointer, self.trajectory_start_index = 0, 0

##########*****####################*****##########

#################### Models ####################

class Actor(Model):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.action_dim = num_actions
        self.dense1_layer = layers.Dense(256, activation="relu")
        self.dense2_layer = layers.Dense(256, activation="relu")
        self.mean_layer = layers.Dense(self.action_dim)
        self.stdev_layer = layers.Dense(self.action_dim)

    def call(self, state, eval_mode=False):

        a1 = self.dense1_layer(state)
        a2 = self.dense2_layer(a1)
        mu = self.mean_layer(a2)

        log_sigma = self.stdev_layer(a2)
        sigma = tf.exp(log_sigma)

        covar_m = tf.linalg.diag(sigma**2)

        dist = tfp.distributions.MultivariateNormalTriL(loc=mu, scale_tril=tf.linalg.cholesky(covar_m))
        if eval_mode:
            action_ = mu
        else:
            action_ = dist.sample()

        action = tf.tanh(action_)

        log_pi_ = dist.log_prob(action_)

        log_pi = log_pi_ - tf.reduce_sum(tf.math.log(tf.clip_by_value(1 - action**2, EPSILON, 1.0)), axis=1)     

        return action*upper_bound, log_pi

def get_critic():
    state_input = layers.Input(shape=(num_states))
    state_out = layers.Dense(256, activation="relu")(state_input)

    out = layers.Dense(256, activation="relu")(state_out)
    outputs = layers.Dense(1, dtype='float32')(out)

    model = tf.keras.Model(state_input, outputs)

    return model

##########*****####################*****##########

#################### GLOBAL SETUP P2 ####################

# Hyperparameters of the PPO algorithm
horizon = 2048
iterations = 2000
gamma = 0.99
clip_ratio = 0.2
epochs = 500
lam = 0.97
target_kl = 0.01
beta = 1.0
render = False

actor_model = Actor()
critic_model = get_critic()

lr = 0.0003

policy_optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=lr,
                                                            # )
                                                clipnorm=1.0)

value_optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=lr,
                                                            # )
                                                clipnorm=1.0)

buffer = Buffer(num_states, num_actions, horizon)


##########*****####################*****##########


#################### Training ####################

observation, episode_return, episode_length = env.reset(), 0, 0
tf_observation = tf.expand_dims(observation, 0)

def train_policy(
    observation_buffer, action_buffer, logprobability_buffer, advantage_buffer
):
    global beta
    with tf.GradientTape() as tape:  # Record operations for automatic differentiation.
        action, log_a = actor_model(observation_buffer)
        # print("A: ", tf.reduce_mean(action))
        # print("LOG_A: ", tf.reduce_mean(log_a))
        ratio = tf.exp(
            log_a
            - logprobability_buffer
        )
        # print("R: ", tf.reduce_mean(ratio), flush=True)
        cd_ratio = tf.clip_by_value(ratio, (1 - clip_ratio), (1 + clip_ratio))
        min_advantage = cd_ratio * advantage_buffer

        _kl = -beta*tf.math.reduce_max(logprobability_buffer - log_a)
        policy_loss = -tf.reduce_mean(tf.minimum(ratio * advantage_buffer, min_advantage) + _kl)
        # print("LOSS: ", policy_loss)
    policy_grads = tape.gradient(policy_loss, actor_model.trainable_variables)
    policy_optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(policy_grads, actor_model.trainable_variables))
    # print("GRAD: ", policy_grads[0], flush=True)
    action_opt, log_a_opt = actor_model(observation_buffer)
    kl = tf.reduce_mean(
        logprobability_buffer
        - log_a_opt
    )

    if kl < target_kl/1.5:
        beta = beta/2
    if kl > target_kl*1.5:
        beta = beta*2

    return kl

def train_value_function(observation_buffer, return_buffer):
    with tf.GradientTape() as tape:  # Record operations for automatic differentiation.
        value_loss = tf.reduce_mean((return_buffer - critic_model(observation_buffer)) ** 2)
    value_grads = tape.gradient(value_loss, critic_model.trainable_variables)
    value_optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(value_grads, critic_model.trainable_variables))


for ite in range(iterations):



    for t in range(horizon):
        if render:
            env.render()


        action, log_pi_a = actor_model(tf_observation)
        action = action[0]

        observation_new, reward, done, _ = env.step(action)

        episode_return += reward
        episode_length += 1


        value_t = critic_model(tf_observation)


        buffer.store(observation, action, reward, value_t, log_pi_a)


        observation = observation_new
        tf_observation = tf.expand_dims(observation, 0)


        terminal = done
        if terminal or (t == horizon - 1):
            last_value = 0 if done else critic_model(tf_observation)
            buffer.finish_trajectory(last_value)
            observation, episode_return, episode_length = env.reset(), 0, 0
            tf_observation = tf.expand_dims(observation, 0)


    for _ in range(epochs):

        (
            observation_buffer,
            action_buffer,
            advantage_buffer,
            return_buffer,
            logprobability_buffer,
        ) = buffer.get()

        kl = train_policy(
            observation_buffer, action_buffer, logprobability_buffer, advantage_buffer
        )

        train_value_function(observation_buffer, return_buffer)

    buffer.clear()


##########*****####################*****##########
```

**Note:**

1. The code base is constructed by a combination of a modified version of the official keras PPO tutorial(*https://keras.io/examples/rl/ppo_cartpole/*) and Modules(Mainly the policy network) that have been tested in other implementations.
2. I refrained from using tf_function declaration as I am very new to tensorflow, thus not understanding its impact, and I have read from various github issues that sometimes such declaration causes numerical instability due to caching. However, it could be a source of my issues.

Any help is appreciated, and apologies if something is missing or unclear.

Comment: Were you able to fix this bug?

Comment: @desert_ranger yes, i believe so, i revamped almost everything and i think it had something to do with numerical instability from the computation in def train_policy. But i have since moved onto other projects and i cant recall what exactly was wrong.